# Where can I find a current wxPerl PPM?

Tags: perl, wxperl

On September 24, 2009 Sep 24, 2009 wxPerl 0.93 was released to CPAN.

Does anyone know where I can get a current ppm version of wxPerl 0.93 for Active Perl 5.10

The repositories (besides activestate.com) I know and visited are:

- [wxperl.co.uk](http://www.wxperl.co.uk/ppm.html)  (last version Feb 2009)
- [trouchelle.com](http://trouchelle.com/perl/ppmrepview.pl?l=W&v=10) (shows a fail status for Wx .93)
- [cpan.uwinnipeg.ca](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/PPMPackages/10xx/) (Wx-Perl not found)
- [www.bribes.org](http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppmdir.html) (Wx-Perl not found)

**edit:** I have a previous version of wxPerl installed and working, but would like to move to the latest release, I am coding for mac, linux, win32 and need to be at the same level on each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no valid ppm for the latest WxPerl release.

This could either indicate WxPerl is no longer used/needed or that most developers have switched to Strawberry Perl and it's embedded c-compiler.

I will update/delete this answer as soon as I find a valid ppm .. and will go and try strawberry on my test machine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try downloading directly from [wxperl.sourceforge.net](http://wxperl.sourceforge.net/) and installing that.

You may also need to install `Alien::wxWidgets` and `wxMSW` form [here](http://wxwidgets.org/downloads/) and of course `Wxwidget`

Comment: No, I didn't try that. Since wxPerl needs to communicate with wxwidgets, I assumed that a XS interface was required. From that I included that a direct install doesn't work. **Are you saying it does work?**

Comment: I didn't try it out. I just reposted information I found on how others did get it working. (As you are from swiss the german post might help you http://reneeb-perlblog.blogspot.com/2008/10/schwieriger-start-mit-wxperl-ppm.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately it doesn't help.  I have previous versions of wxPerl working, thats how I knew the repositories, but cannot find a ppm (special format wrapper for ActiveState's perl) of the latest wxPerl release on any of them. I guess a move to strawberry isn't too far in the future. Active perl is just too much grief!

Answer (score 0):

I can't find ppm either. Padre requires wx, so both still seem to be used. Standard way of installing these days seems to be via Alien::wxWidgets. They say it's easy to install, but I can't do it on strawberry right now.

EDIT: ActiveState provides a PPM. Wx is version 0.9909

EDIT: There seems to be a package (no ppm) on cygports, see http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/